# code to create all possible pairs of colums in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, combinatorics

For the following df:

```py
data=[['TAMU', 54, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0,],['UIUC', 33, 43, 5, 0, 76, 81],
['USC',4, 1, 0, 7, 21, 4], ['Austin',22,31, 0, 0,55, 0],
['UCLA', 55, 6, 7, 9, 11,12]]
pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Name', 'Research', 'Thesis', 
'Proposal', 'AI', 'Analytics', 'Data'])
```

I want to create contingency tables for all possible column combinations (eg: AI,Analytics  --Data,AI) of two specified rows  (say USC and UCLA) to feed to my chisquare function.

```py
def overflow(school1,school2,alpha):
    pvals_list=[]
    data=[['TAMU', 54, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0,],['UIUC', 33, 43, 5, 0, 76, 81],
['USC',4, 1, 0, 7, 21, 4], ['Austin',22,31, 0, 0,55, 0],
['UCLA', 55, 6, 7, 9, 11,12]]
     pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Name', 'Research', 'Thesis', 'Proposal', 
'AI', 'Analytics', 'Data'])
    df=df[(df['Unnamed: 0'] == school1) | (df['Unnamed: 0'] == school2)]
    df=df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
    df=df.set_index('Name')
    ###
    ####code to create columns pairs [for loop?]to feed to data_crosstab  below
    ###
        
           data_crosstab = pd.crosstab()
           chi,p_vals = stats.chi2_contingency(data_crosstab)[:2]
           if p > alpha:
               pvals_list.appned(p_vals)
   return(pvals_list)
overflow('USC','UCLA',0.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the two data to `pd.crosstab` to create `RxC Table`:

```py
>>> data_crosstab = pd.crosstab(df.loc['USC'], df.loc['UCLA'])
UCLA  6   7   9   11  12  55
USC                         
0      0   1   0   0   0   0
1      1   0   0   0   0   0
4      0   0   0   0   1   1
7      0   0   1   0   0   0
21     0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Then you can pass it to `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` to get the result:

```py
>>> stats.chi2_contingency(pd.crosstab(df.loc['USC'], df.loc['UCLA']))
(24.000000000000014,
 0.24239216167051175,
 20,
 array([[0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
        0.16666667],
       [0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
        0.16666667],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333,
        0.33333333],
       [0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
        0.16666667],
       [0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667, 0.16666667,
        0.16666667]]))

#chi is the first value i.e. 24 and p_vals is second value i.e. 0.24232
```

For a pair of row indices, above will work fine, you just  need to replace `USC` and `UCLA`.

If you want to do it for all the rows,  you can loop it using `combinations` from `itertools` on the index values:

```
from itertools import combinations
for left, right in combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2):
    data_crosstab = pd.crosstab(df.loc[left], df.loc[right])

    #rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
[x for x in combinations(['Name', 'Research', 'Thesis', 
'Proposal', 'AI', 'Analytics', 'Data'], 2)]
```

out:

```
[('Name', 'Research'),
 ('Name', 'Thesis'),
 ('Name', 'Proposal'),
 ('Name', 'AI'),
 ('Name', 'Analytics'),
 ('Name', 'Data'),
 ('Research', 'Thesis'),
 ('Research', 'Proposal'),
 ('Research', 'AI'),
 ('Research', 'Analytics'),
 ('Research', 'Data'),
 ('Thesis', 'Proposal'),
 ('Thesis', 'AI'),
 ('Thesis', 'Analytics'),
 ('Thesis', 'Data'),
 ('Proposal', 'AI'),
 ('Proposal', 'Analytics'),
 ('Proposal', 'Data'),
 ('AI', 'Analytics'),
 ('AI', 'Data'),
 ('Analytics', 'Data')]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
for col1, col2 in combinations(df.set_index("Name").columns,2):
    #add your code here
```

The result of using `combinations` is:

```
>>> list(combinations(df.set_index("Name").columns,2))
[('Research', 'Thesis'),
 ('Research', 'Proposal'),
 ('Research', 'AI'),
 ('Research', 'Analytics'),
 ('Research', 'Data'),
 ('Thesis', 'Proposal'),
 ('Thesis', 'AI'),
 ('Thesis', 'Analytics'),
 ('Thesis', 'Data'),
 ('Proposal', 'AI'),
 ('Proposal', 'Analytics'),
 ('Proposal', 'Data'),
 ('AI', 'Analytics'),
 ('AI', 'Data'),
 ('Analytics', 'Data')]
```